# Accessing local network with Cordova UWP app

Tags: cordova, uwp, phonegap, cordova-win10

I have a cordova app (SPA) and need to make an XmlHttpRequest to a local network resource.

If the app is in [**remote mode**](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/windows/#understanding-remote-mode-vs-local-mode), I am not able/allowed to define the necessary `privateNetworkClientServer` capability (the app was actually rejected in the Windows Store because I defined this capability while remote mode was enabled). Without `privateNetworkClientServer` XmlHttpRequests to the local network do not work.

If the app is in **local mode**, I can define the necessary `privateNetworkClientServer` capability but I am also getting a lot of errors/warning:

```
CSP14312: Resource violated directive 'script-src ms-appx: data: 'unsafe-eval'' in Host Defined Policy: inline script. Resource will be blocked
```

This is probably because I am using jQuery to dynamically create/update the app contents, like $("#myelement").html(...) ?

So I am kind of stuck here. In both modes I am facing issues.

Is there any way to make a XmlHttpRequest to a local network resource without defining the privateNetworkClientServer capability?
Is there any other way I should create the single page app, which is compatible with local mode?

Answer (score 0):

It should be the **Content-Security-Policy** that caused this issue, see the [connect-src document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/connect-src),

> The HTTP Content-Security-Policy (CSP) connect-src directive restricts the URLs which can be loaded using script interfaces.

You can try to add your local network URL  to the `connect-src` resource directive in your `index.html` file's first meta `Content-Security-Policy`'s content. As the following code, you can replace **YOUR NETWORK URL** with your URL.

```
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src connect-src YOUR NETWORK URL  'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion, however I am not trying to connect to localhost but to another server on the local network.

Comment: @Dominic I have modified my answer, please have a check and try to add your URL to the Content-Security-Policy content.

Comment: Hi, the app should be able to communicate within the users network. The IP is defined at runtime within the App. Unfortunately I do not know the network URL at development time...